# user group gets page access

Tags: magento

i would like to add this functionality to a Magento store

2 user types

1 = have purchased
2 = have not purchased

the have purchased group has extra tab in user account that might have a variety of things like a free download and/or link to page that only have purchased can access.

Comment: Okay, but what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use customer groups for this. Add most users to the default group, and add an event listener to completed orders that changes the user's group. Then only allow access to the page based on the customer's group.